# OpenGL - glDrawElements only draws half polygon

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a problem right now when implementing indices in opengl for Android. I think I am almost there - but the problem is that only half of the polygon is drawn. What could be the reason for this and how to solve it?

1
create and bind buffers, one `FloatBuffer` for positions and uvcoords, one `ShortBuffer` for indices

```
    public int createVBO(ArrayList <SpriteDataHolder> spriteDataList) {

    final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
    final int BYTES_PER_SHORT = 2;
    final int N_SPRITES = spriteDataList.size();
    final int N_VERTICES_SPRITE = spriteDataList.get(0).getSpriteVertices().length; //godtyckligt indexvärde - alla lika
    final int N_UVS_SPRITE = spriteDataList.get(0).getUvsSprites().length;
    final int N_INDICES_SPRITE = 6;
    final int totalDataLength = N_SPRITES * (N_VERTICES_SPRITE + N_UVS_SPRITE);
    final int totalDataLengthShort = N_SPRITES * N_INDICES_SPRITE;

    final int POSITION_DATA_SIZE = 3; // antal floats per punktcoordinat
    final int TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE = 2; // antal floats per uvcoordinat
    final int INDEX_DATA_SIZE = 1; // antal shorts per indexvärde

    final FloatBuffer spriteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(totalDataLength * BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

    final ShortBuffer indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(totalDataLengthShort * BYTES_PER_SHORT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();

    int spritePositionOffset = 0;
    int spriteTextureOffset = 0;
    int spriteIndexOffset = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N_SPRITES; i++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < 6; v++) { // 6 punkter per polygon

            spriteBuffer.put(spriteDataList.get(i).getSpriteVertices(), spritePositionOffset, POSITION_DATA_SIZE); // vertices x y z för sprite i
            spritePositionOffset += POSITION_DATA_SIZE;

            spriteBuffer.put(spriteDataList.get(i).getUvsSprites(), spriteTextureOffset, TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE);
            spriteTextureOffset += TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE;

            indexBuffer.put(spriteDataList.get(i).getIndices(), spriteIndexOffset, INDEX_DATA_SIZE);
            spriteIndexOffset += INDEX_DATA_SIZE;
        }
        spritePositionOffset = 0;
        spriteTextureOffset = 0;
        spriteIndexOffset = 0;
    }

    spriteBuffer.position(0);
    indexBuffer.position(0);

    // skicka flyttalsbufferten till GPU'N
    final int buffers[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, spriteBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, spriteBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    final int[] indexbuffers = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, indexbuffers, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_SHORT, indexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    return buffers[0];
}
```

2 // and the created indices for all sprites

```
    private void createVBOindices(short[][] indices, int nSprites) {

    int last = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSprites; i++) {

        indices[i][0] = (short)(last + 0);
        indices[i][1] = (short)(last + 1);
        indices[i][2] = (short)(last + 2);
        indices[i][3] = (short)(last + 1);
        indices[i][4] = (short)(last + 3);
        indices[i][5] = (short)(last + 2);

        last = last + 4;
    }
}
```

I have this order since this is the order that follows the vertices that is ...

```
 TRIANGLE 1

  0     2 
  x x x x        
  x    x
  x  x
  x
  1

 TRIANGLE 2

        2
        x        
      x x
    x   x 
  x x x x 
  1     3
```

so for the first triangle it draws from 0 to 1 and then to 2 and for the second triangle it draws from 1 to 3 and then to 2.

I thougt the problem could be found here that is the drawingorder of the second triangle but a have tried several combinations but the second triangle will not be drawed.

Heres  the drawcall in the drawmethod

```
 GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: The loop 'for (int v = 0; v < 6; v++)' filling out spriteBuffer seems to indicate you have 6 vertices per sprite. Using indexed rendering you should have 6 indices per sprite but only 4 vertices. Is it possible you're filling out spriteDataList wrong?

Comment: @Columbo - ok I thought it should be 6 - so if you are correct about this the answer is YES - I should change spriteDataList-filling. I guess the same applies to uv-coords?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the comment from Columbo fixed this one, but the winding of your triangles is different so if you have `GL_CULL_FACE` enabled then it's possible that your second triangle is classified as back-facing.

Either disable the facing test, or change the index order in the second triangle so both are facial the same way.